# How to keep track of who created a JUnit test and when using Eclipse? How to create statistics based on this information?

Tags: eclipse, junit

In a Java project I'm working (alongside a team of 8 devs), we have a large backlog of features that lack automated tests. We are covering this backlog and we need to keep track of who wrote a JUnit test and when, plus we have to measure how many test we wrote as a team in a week/month/semester (as you may have figured out already, this information is for management purposes). We figured we'd do this by marking the tests with the information we need (author, creation date) and let Eclipse do the processing work, showing us tests we wrote, who wrote'em and how far we were from reaching our goals. How would you smart people go about this? What plugins would you use?

I tried to use Eclipse Custom Tags for this, but it's not the purpose of the feature, and the results I got were kind of brittle. I created a TEST tag that was supposed to mark a test method. It looks like this: (date is mm-dd-yyyy)

//TEST my.name 08-06-2011

Since Eclipse processes tag description by substringing (contains/doesn't contain), it's, as I said, very brittle. I can timestamp the tag, but it's just a string. Eclipse can't process it as a date, compare dates, filter by date interval, stuff like that.

I searched for plugins, but no dice.

My B-plan is to create an Annotation with the information we need and process our test packages using Eclipse Annotation Processing Tool. I haven't tried anything on this front yet, though, just an idea. Anyone knows a good plugin for this kind of Annotation processing? Or any starter tips for dealing with Eclipse APT.

Thanks a bunch, folks

Comment: I'd probably look to my source control to handle this - what SCM do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use Eclipse for this.

Your team should be checking the tests into a version control system such as Subversion, Git, Team Foundation Server, etc. From there it should a fairly straightforward matter to determine the owner and check-in time. You can and *should* do this sort of metrics calculation during every build. Better yet, be sure that your build script actually runs your tests and uses a tool like EMMA to instrument the code and determine the actual coverage.

As a fallback for measuring coverage, if you choose a naming convention then you may even be able to correlate the test classes by file name back to the feature under test.

Many modern build systems, such as CruiseControl, have integration for doing these sorts of things quite nicely.

Comment: We (still) use CVS for Version Control and Jenkins (former Hudson) for Continuous Integration. I actually did a little research on how to do this using Jenkins before turning to Eclipse, but had no good results. 

We are moving to Git in the next few months (thankfully), I guess we will use Eclipse for now and, when we migrate to Git, I'll follow your suggestion. Thanks a bunch.